# How to stop a python socket.accept() call?

Tags: python, sockets

I am a newbie in python sockets and am really troubled by the stubbornness of the `socket.accept()` method. I really need a way of ending a `socket.accept()` method or any other alternative to `socket.accept()` which runs one time only.

Comment: You should check out the `socket.setblocking` function and the [`select`](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html) module.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have several options here:

1. Close the listening socket from another thread - the `accept()` will raise an exception if it fails.
2. Open a local connection to the listening socket - that makes the `accept()` return by design.
3. Use an accept mechanism that can block on more than one synchronization object so that the wait can be signaled to return without a connection.
4. Use a non-blocking alternative to `accept()`, (async like `AcceptEx()` and overlapped IO on Windows).

Comment: @NiklasB. - thanks.  I don't have any Python, but the OP question is more a general TCP server issue and the same set of 'tricks' are needed in all languages.

Comment: Can you give an example because as stated earlier i am a newbie....i am actually writing a server in pygtk. My problem is that the window hangs because of the socket.accept() call.

Comment: On OSX 10.10 with Python 2.7.6, (1) is unreliable. However, using a `quit_now` style flag in the accept loop and then connecting (2) to trigger a return from accept() works fine.

Comment: Option #2 seems to be most appropriate for several of my applications.

Comment: Could you show examples of these? You have no idea how useful they'd be.

Comment: Iam trying first method, but it still hangs.